# Translate OpenSSL RSA encryption to GnuTLS

Tags: c, openssl, gnutls

I am attempting to translate the following code from OpenSSL to GnuTLS for licencing reasons:

```
  BIO *bioKey = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
  if (!bioKey)
  {
    DEBUG_ERROR("failed to allocate bioKey");
    spice_disconnect_channel(channel);
    return false;
  }

  BIO_write(bioKey, reply.pub_key, SPICE_TICKET_PUBKEY_BYTES);
  EVP_PKEY *rsaKey = d2i_PUBKEY_bio(bioKey, NULL);
  RSA *rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(rsaKey);

  char enc[RSA_size(rsa)];
  if (RSA_public_encrypt(
        strlen(spice.password) + 1,
        (uint8_t*)spice.password,
        (uint8_t*)enc,
        rsa,
        RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
  ) <= 0)
  {
    DEBUG_ERROR("rsa public encrypt failed");
    spice_disconnect_channel(channel);
    EVP_PKEY_free(rsaKey);
    BIO_free(bioKey);
    return false;
  }

  ssize_t rsaSize = RSA_size(rsa);
  EVP_PKEY_free(rsaKey);
  BIO_free(bioKey);
```

So far I have come up with the following but it seems the output is not in the correct format (RSA_PKCS1_OEAP_PADDING)

```
  const gnutls_datum_t pubData =
  {
    .data = (void *)reply.pub_key,
    .size = SPICE_TICKET_PUBKEY_BYTES
  };

  gnutls_pubkey_t pubkey;
  if (gnutls_pubkey_init(&pubkey) < 0)
  {
    spice_disconnect_channel(channel);
    DEBUG_ERROR("gnutls_pubkey_init failed");
    return false;
  }

  if (gnutls_pubkey_import(pubkey, &pubData, GNUTLS_X509_FMT_DER) < 0)
  {
    gnutls_pubkey_deinit(pubkey);
    spice_disconnect_channel(channel);
    DEBUG_ERROR("gnutls_pubkey_import failed");
    return false;
  }

  const gnutls_datum_t input =
  {
    .data = (void *)spice.password,
    .size = strlen(spice.password) + 1
  };

  gnutls_datum_t out;
  if (gnutls_pubkey_encrypt_data(pubkey, 0, &input, &out) < 0)
  {
    gnutls_pubkey_deinit(pubkey);
    spice_disconnect_channel(channel);
    DEBUG_ERROR("gnutls_pubkey_encrypt_data failed");
    return false;
  }

  const char        *enc     = (char *)out.data;
  const unsigned int rsaSize = out.size;
```

I am no expert with encryption or these libraries, so please be kind.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]

Comment: The code provided above is a complete, minimal and verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

GnuTLS does not support ES-OEAP at all. `gnutls_pubkey_encrypt_data` produces PKCS#1 padded data and can not be used.

The solution is to avoid GnuTLS entirely and perform the encryption manually using nettle and libgmp. I based my solution on the example in FreeTDS:

http://www.freetds.org/reference/a00351_source.html

This implements an OEAP padding function and uses GMP to perform the RSA encryption.